# Using NetworkStream object as a parameter for XDocument.Save (and Load) methods

Tags: c#, xml, network-programming

---

I write a client - server utility which transmits a xml document over TCP network. The simplest way to do it is subj. But how can I use the same stream to write back to the client after the xml was handled on the server? Here one of varints I've tried to use.

server:

```
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
              IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
             TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);
             Listener.Start();
             Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
             TcpClient tcpClient = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
             NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
             XDocument xmlNewInit = XDocument.Load(stream);
  // Send back a response.
             byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Object created!");
             stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

client:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.49");
 IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
    
                 // Create a TCP/IP  socket.  
 TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
                    
    
                 // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.  
    
 tcpClient.Connect(remoteEP);
 textBox.Text = "Socket connected to " + remoteEP.ToString();
    
  NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
 XElement NewInit = new XElement(.....)
 NewInit.Save(stream);
 // Receive the response from the remote device. 
 int bytesRec = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 textBox.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
```

I works fine when I just send the XML. But when I add strings handling the response it freezes infinitely and not even the XML is sent any more.
I've tried also to use AutoResetEvent to wait till the XML is sent and handle the response only after that, but with the same result.
Surely there are means to do the task. Please, help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need some protocol ... fx first send type and size of the message , lets type would be stream and size - size of the xml then send message itself(xml) ... on server side you read type and if it's stream then create wrapper stream with given size (since NetworkStream  will not have size defined) ... in othere case `XDocument.Load` oesn't really know when xml stream ends (and it prolly work because you were disconnecting client)

Comment: How can you tell when each part of the message terminates?  Like Selvin say you need a protocol when when sending data.  The end of data is determined by one of three methods 1) Terminate with a known character not part of message 2) Precede message with a byte/char count 3) Send fixed length messages.